# How to chain rxjs observables to get value of inner observable and return with parent in Angular

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, rxjs, observable

I make a request to firestore to get a user's chats and it returns an observable array of objects with this shape

```
[...,
  {
     key: '83hed87djhe09',
     participants: ['owner_43', 'visitor_69']
  },
...]
```

This displays a list of all user's chats in the UI, however I'd like to search for chats by user name. In order to do that, I'd have to make a http request to a backend server for the user name of each participant and replace that in the participants thread to make it searchable on type.

So 'owner_43' would become 'John Doe' for example.

Problem I'm experiencing is that I get an array of observables for the participant names rather than an array of strings.

[image]

Here's my code

```js
this.chat$ = this.chatSvc.getUserChats(this.userUID).pipe(
  map((chats: any) => {
    return chats.map((chat: any) => {
      return {
        key: chat.key,
        participants: chat.participants.map((participant: any) => {
          return this.userSvc.getUserFromString(participant);
        })
      }
    })
  })
);
```

Here's the getUserFromString function:

```js
getUserFromString(stringId){

  let splitValue = stringId.split("_");
  let accountType = splitValue[0];
  let id = splitValue[1];

  if (accountType === 'owner') {
    return this.ownerSvc.getOwner(id);
  }
  else if (accountType === 'visitor') {
    return this.visitorSvc.getVisitor(id);
  }
}
```

Get owner function simply returns:

```js
return this.http.get(owner_url + id);
```

Finally the result is unwrapped in the view using the angular async pipe

```html
<ul><li *ngFor="let msg of chat$|async">{{msg.key}}</li></ul>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Assuming your `Chat` looks like this:**

```js
/**
 * Type parameter is being used
 * due to participants initially being of type string[]
 * and ultimately of type User[]
 */
class Chat<T> {
  key: string;
  participants: T[]
}
```

**Consider the following implementation:**

```js
this.chat$: Observable<Chat<User>[]> = this.chatSvc.getUserChats(this.userUID).pipe(
  mergeAll(),
  mergeMap(({ key, participants }: Chat<string>) => {
    return forkJoin(participants.map(this.userSvc.getUserFromString)).pipe(
      map(participants => ({ key, participants }))
    )
  }),
  toArray()
)
```

**Explanation (Simplified):**

```js
this.chat$ = this.chatSvc.getUserChats(this.userUID).pipe(

/**
 * flattens Observable<Chat[]> into a stream
 * of Observable<Chat> so we can handle single Chat at a time
 */
  mergeAll(), 

 /**
  *  transform each Chat into an 
  *  Observable containing a new value
  */
  mergeMap(({ key, participants }: Chat) => {

   /**
    * transform participants (String[]) into an array of Observables 
    * (Observable<User>[])
    */
    const participants$ = participants.map(this.userSvc.getUserFromString)
    
   /**
    *  wait for all Observables to complete using forkJoin
    *  then return new Chat using map
    */
    return forkJoin(participants).pipe(
      map(participants => ({ key: key, participants: participants  }))
    )
  }),
  toArray() // <= transform stream back into array (Observable<Chat[]>)
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I tried implementing this but it keeps returning the error: cannot read property 'ownerSvc' of undefined at getUserFromString.

Seems to have something to do with the 'this' keyword, do you have any ideas of how to workaround it?

Comment: fixed it.  (`participants.map(x => this.userSvc.getUserFromString(x))` instead of `participants.map(this.userSvc.getUserFromString)`)

Comment: That fixed the issue! The solution works right up until toArray() i.e it makes the query for the user's data and sets the result to `{ key: 'key_id', participants: [ {participant_object_1}, {participant_object_2} ]} ` for each message but doesn't return all the messages

Comment: is `getUserChats` a Subject or HttpClient request?

Comment: It's a HttpClient request

Comment: try placing some operator below`toArray` operator and see if it hits there

Comment: also try using `first()` operator right above `mergeAll`